# Compare and highlight the different in 2 pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a python code to check 2 pandas Dataframe, using a unique ID to look for the record in both Dataframe and compare the different. It will need to highlight duplicate lines and export the full record:

eg, unique ID = Order_id:

df1:

```
id  Name    Order_id  Product   Qty
0   John    33321     Apple     1
1   Peter   22256     Orange    2
2   Mary    11112     Apple     12
```

df2:

```
id  Name    Order_id   Product  Qty
0   John    33321      apple    12
1   Peter   22256      Orange   2
2   Mary    11112      Apple    12
3   Joe     22223      Pear     6
4   Mary    11112      Apple    12
```

And output after compare it should be in a Dataframe / text file like below:

```
File 1 Header:  id  Name    Order_id    Product Qty
File 2 Header:  id  Name    Order_id    Product Qty

File 1:         0   John    33321      Apple    1
File 2:         0   John    33321      apple    12
diff:                                  ^         ^

File 1:         2   Mary    11112      Apple    12
File 2:         2   Mary    11112      Apple    12
File 2:         4   Mary    11112      Apple    12
diff:           ^               

File 1:         nan  nan    nan        nan      nan
File 2:         3    Joe    22223      Pear     6
diff:          Missing Missing  Missing Missing Missing
```

I am able to get the different records, however, I am not sure how to put them in a Dataframe, it end up have error:

```
diff_val = np.where((df1 != df2).any(1) == True)
df_result = pd.DataFrame(df1.columns)
for item in diff_val:
    df_result.append(df1.iloc[item], df2.iloc[item])
```

I also tried to put in a text file, but it is not able to show like the format above.
Is there any suggestion? Tks.

Comment: This looks like too much work for me.  I'd suggest breaking the question up.  But in the spirit of being helpful, I'd start off with `merge` and `indicator=True`.  With that you can group by `Order_id` where `_merge` is `both` and use numpy broadcasting to get a complete array of all differences among the rows with identical `Order_id`s.  If that sounds like a lot to you... I'd agree with you.